# Necessity of auto-incrementing ID

Tags: mysql

Every implementation of a credentials table I've seen has an auto-incrmenting id to to track users.

However,

If I verify unique email addresses before inserting into a mySQL table, than I can guarantee the uniqueness of each row by email address...furthermore I can access the table as needed through the email address..

Does anyone see a problem with this?

I'm trying to understand why others don't follow this approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those email addresses are much larger than 4 bytes, perhaps even worse for the storage engine they are variable length.

Also one person might want two accounts, or might have several email addresses over time.

Then there are the problems associated with case folding.

Comment: Case folding means comparing strings by comparing their lower or upper case forms so that users can type their address without worrying about caps.

Comment: @stack.user That would be true if each address was stored once. The question is about using them as user identifiers, in which case they will be stored many times in every other table that needs to refer to a user.

Answer (score 2):

When other tables have data that relates to users, what do you use as a foreign key?  Their email address?  What if they want to change their email address?  What would have been a single one-row update now becomes a giant mess.

A generated key allows you to decouple data that can change from the relationships between records and tables.

Comment: @stack.user.3 It can, but it is a common good practise to use surrogate keys, because it cannot change.

Comment: Regardless of the argument for space -- email address is not a fixed piece of information.  The data you use to make relations between tables should be fairly fixed to the rows they belong to.  You can use whatever you want as a key value, but you should optimally pick something that will NEVER change because of the cascading effects of updating dependent rows.  Email address (to me) does not meet this criteria.